# How to sort a csv file by rows after it has been imported onto python

Tags: python, sorting, csv, python-3.x

The csv file is 18 columns and 45000 rows. it is imported using these codes (it contains special characters)

```
import csv

with open('airports.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for row in csv.reader(file):
        print(row)
```

how would i sort this by columns?
any example code or references i can look at would be appreciated.

Comment: does it make sense to have a table with 45,000 columns? Or do you mean 45,000 rows?

Comment: [sorted](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) built-in function

Comment: it has 45, 000 verticle lines and 18 horizontal lines to be clear my mistake i corrected it

Comment: How do you want to sort them?

Comment: by columns which are the categories

Comment: If you want to sort them by multiple (18?) columns at the same time, you'll need to describe what order the values in each column are considered in.

Answer (score 1):

The [Python Sorting HOW TO](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) has some good information.  If you get the contents of your CSV file into a list, you can use the techniques documented there.

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip`:

```
import csv

with open('airports.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    rows = [r for r in csv.reader(file)]

columns = zip(*rows)
```

Example:

rows = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

for row in rows: print(row)

columns = zip(*rows)

for column in columns: print(column)

Give it a shot

Comment: How does this sort them?

Comment: Give it a try, zip(*x) returns an iterator for the transpose of x.  So you can go column by column rather than row by row.

Comment: I know what zip does. Transposing x is not the same thing as sorting it.

Comment: ok, well then, more info needed on what "sort by column" means

Comment: I think transpose means [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) although I suppose that abstractly it could be considered a kind of sequence-ordering/collating operation.

Comment: I often read csv files, and want only one or two columns worth of info. I use zip(*rows) to do this. Sorry if this was not helpful.